# Servidor dedicado Linux CentosOS

Tags: linux, servidor, terminal

Tengo problemas con mi servidor, no tengo servicios apache, correos, mysql, por lo que no tengo paginas web.
Revise el estado de mis servicios y aparecen arriba.

Pero al ejecutar el siguiente comando: `sudo systemctl status httpd.service`
Muestra el siguiente mensage donde me dice que esta inactivo, adjunto la siguiente imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentando habilitar el servicio con los siguiente comandos:

```
sudo httpd start
sudo service httpd start
sudo systemctl start httpd.service
sudo systemctl enable httpd.service
```

Hasta ahora no he podido hablilitar el servicio con esos comandos, pero me pudan ayudar.
Buen dia.

Comment: ¿Utilizas cPanel?

Comment: Si falla el comando al intentar levantarlo muy probablemente le metiste alguna configuracion que esta rompiendo el servicio, debe haber alguna informacion en el log del S.O ...

Comment: ¿Cuál versión de CentOS? Agrega el mensaje completo donde dice `condition failed`.

Comment: Es cPanel WHM
y el condition failed indica :  ConditionPathExists=!/etc/apachedisabled was not met

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.